Seeking a Restartable Timeout Hook in React
I'm building an app that displays images.  Over top of each image, I wish to display an informative tooltip, but upon the mouse moving over top of the image, I want the tooltip to only display about 0.5 seconds after.
To this end, I have implemented this React Hook:
import * as React from 'react';

/**
 * This is a React Hook implementation of the window.setTimeout function.
 * Source: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/react-hooks/use-timeout
 * 
 * @param {callback} onTimerDone 
 * @param {number} delay - milliseconds
 */
export const useTimeout = (onTimerDone: () => void, delay: number) => {
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(0);
  const savedCallback = React.useRef(onTimerDone);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = onTimerDone;
  }, [onTimerDone]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => savedCallback.current();
    timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(tick, delay);

    return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current); // Cleanup function
  }, [delay]);

  return timeoutRef;
};

I tried several approaches but can only get this timer hook to fire once.  I'm looking for a timer that acts like a restartable timer.  In other words, the timer will start counting down again & again whenever I instruct it to.
I can't figure out how to implement a Timeout hook that works in the way I need it to.  Can anyone provide any suggestions?

If you need tooltip to show up after timeout you need to use event handler, not useEffect.
// reusable hook to schedule timeouts
function useTimeoutTask() {
  const timer = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();

  const cancel = useCallback(() => {
    if (timer.current) {
      clearTimeout(timer.current);
      timer.current = undefined;
    }
  }, []);

  const schedule = useCallback((handler: () => void, timeout: number) => {
    // we only allow one active timeout at a time
    cancel();

    timer.current = setTimeout(handler, timeout);
  }, []);

  // Clear timeout on unmount
  useEffect(() => () => cancel(), []);

  return {
    schedule,
    cancel,
  };
}

// and example of application
function useTooltip() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
  const { cancel, schedule } = useTimeoutTask();

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    // setup task inside event handler
    schedule(() => {
      setShowTooltip(true);
    }, 500);
  };

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    // cancel tooltip in case mouse leaves before tooltip was shown
    cancel();
    setShowTooltip(false);
  };
}


This looks very interesting!  I will try implementing your approach.  Thank you!
